# Delphi: TabStop problems of TRadioButton

Tags: delphi, focus, radio-button, selection

When TRadioButton has TabStop=True, it's acting very strange.

If you will try to switch focus between many radio buttons on a form using Tab key, you would do it only 1 time per app session. The tabulation is one-way, never returning back to the first radio button. Also when the focus is moving across radio buttons, they becoming "checked" automatically.

Can this behavior be fixed without creating my own component?

I want standard radio buttons to

1. switch focus cyclically
2. prevent radio button from checking when the focus comes into it (I want my users to check them using Space key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you're working with existing code, which is a real world constraint that's too often dismissed in these forums.

Sounds to me like checkboxes would suit you better. You can enforce the exclusivity normally expected of RadioButtons in the OnChecked event. That should solve your tabbing/focus and selection/deselection issues.

Checkboxes won't be checked automatically upon receiving focus, and your users can check/uncheck them with the space key.

Comment: I select this answer because using checkboxes is the most simple solution of the problem as I see. However, I need exactly radio buttons, and I'll create a component with modified behaviour for tabulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can put code in the `OnEnter` event to prevent the checkbox from selecting.
You'll need to store the previously selected `RadioButton` somehow though.

```
var
  SelectedRadioButton: TRadioButton;

//event shared by all radiobuttons
procedure TForm1.RadioButton1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender <> SelectedRadioButton then begin
    SelectedRadioButton.Checked:= true;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrameOrder.RadioButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SelectedRadioButton:= (Sender as TRadioButton);
end;

procedure TFrameOrder.RadioButton1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  MyRadioButton: TRadioButton;
begin
  MyRadioButton:= (Sender as TRadioButton);
  if Key in [#32,#13] then begin 
    MyRadioButton.Checked:= true;
    RadioButton1Click(MyRadioButton);
  end; {if}
end;
```

It probably clearer to create a new TMyRadioButton component though because this will clutter up your regular code.

Comment: Thanks, Johan. I tried this solution, but the problem is deeper than it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an [interesting article of Craig Stuntz](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/02/02/37987/) about this problem. As I can see, I'll need to create my own control to solve it.

Comment: You only need to do that if you really want to be able to tab between *all* the related radio buttons. That's not normally how radio buttons work, though. You tab into the *group* of radio buttons, and then use the arrow keys (or accelerator characters) to select which one should be checked. Only the checked one should be a tab stop.

Comment: @Rob, I understand the standard situation, but I need to solve a little bit uncommon task, when radio buttons are not in the single group, but the parts of different controls. So I want to have the complete control on selection and checking.

Answer (score 1):

By default only one RadioButon has property TabStop = True;
All Radiobuttons are treated as one controll.
When radiobutton has focus you can switch beetween radiobutons using arrow up and down.

Now when user choose one option they can press tab to switch to another controll (without changing radio options).